# Column name conflicts with SQL Function when adding new rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

I have a table with 3 columns (System, SES and KL). I want to copy 1 row of that table, change the Value of SES from 120 to 100 and KL from 150 to 10 and add it as a new row. The Column name 'System' is conflicting with an SQL statement and becoming blue highlighted..??

[image]

This is my code:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(System, SES, KL)
SELECT System, "100", "10"
  FROM my_table
 WHERE SES AND KL = "120", "150"
```

Comment: Call it something else

Comment: @Strawberry I cant change my Column name System because it actually gets loaded in from a file content. That means I have to change all the file content which is not possible..

Comment: SYSTEM (R); added in 8.0.3 (reserved) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-S And what do you mean by loaded in from a file content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks : `` ` `` when using reserved keyword.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (`System`, SES, KL)
SELECT `System`, '100', '10'
FROM my_table
WHERE SES = '120' AND KL = '150';
```

You can find bactick above tab key in your keyboard.

Also your `where` condition was wrong.

Comment: @Premier12 Glad to help. Welcome

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your `WHERE` clause is slightly off:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (System, SES, KL)
SELECT System, '100', '10'
FROM my_table
WHERE SES = '120' AND KL = '150';
```

Comment: You've just added an ; after "150"? But System stays blue and is giving an error...

Comment: No, I made other changes, check again.  And...what is the error now?

Comment: Still the same :(